# Create a tuple with double digit values from input in Python

Tags: python, input, tuples

I'm trying to create a tuple from input where the values are two digits.

```
tup = tuple(input("enter a tuple"))
```

but when I enter something like `10 11`, I get this:

```
('1', '0', ' ', '1', '1')
```

The intended result is this:

```py
(10, 11)
```

Comment: Python doesn't know you want to split the characters on whitespace unless you tell it with something like: `tuple(input("enter a tuple").split())`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
tup = tuple(int(n) for n in input("Enter a tuple: ").split(" "))
```

This will work for integers of any number of characters as well as negative integers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I'm adding in an additional step here, but this works.

```
Val= "11 12"
Val=Val.split(" ")
Val=[int(x) for x in Val]
tuple(Val)
```

or if you want to one line it:

```
tuple([int(x) for x in raw_input("enter a tuple:").split(" ")])
```

**Edit**
You could also just use the `input` function if you're using python 2.7.

```
Tup=input("enter tuple:")
>(11,12,13)
print(Tup)
  (11, 12, 13)
```

But I believe that executing user input for a program is considered risky and unacceptable.

Comment: Why not use a generator expression instead of turning a list into a tuple? Also, never name a variable the same name a built-in function. In this case, don't name your variable `input`. Also, your code will error on line 2 because `inpust` is not defined.